# Angular lazy loaded component, only loading after refresh

Tags: javascript, angular

I've got a dashboard component in a lazy loaded module.

In my signin component I have a button that navigates to the dashboard component via router.navigate.

However when I click the button, although it navigates to the correct route, it doesn't display the component. It only displays the app component.

However if I refresh the page it ends up loading. Driving me crazy.If i open up a new tab and go to that same route everything works fine. But it seems when I click the button which navigates via routerlink it doesn't load it.

sign-in.component.html

```
<form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button (click) = "authenticateUser()"  class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
</form>


<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

sign-in.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
  moduleId: module.id,
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.scss']
})
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router:Router) { }

  authenticateUser(){
    //Make request to signin endpoint, if successful save profile details and navigate to dashboard
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import Chart from 'chart.js';


@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard-cmp',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html'
})

export class DashboardComponent{
  constructor(){
  }


}
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf = "url=='/sign-up' || url =='/sign-in'">
<!-- <div class = "head">
  <img class = "logo" src = "assets/img/quickList1.jpeg">
  <app-sign-up></app-sign-up>
</div> -->
<div class = "my-container">
  <div [ngStyle] = "{'height':url == '/sign-up' ? '500px' : '300px' }" class = "form-box">
    <h1 style = "text-align:center;margin-top:12px;">QuickList {{url}}</h1>
    <div class = "signForm">
        <div *ngIf="url == '/sign-in'; else elseBlock"><app-sign-in></app-sign-in></div>
        <ng-template #elseBlock><app-sign-up></app-sign-up></ng-template>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "alternate-box">
    <div class = "prompt">
      <div *ngIf="url == '/sign-in'; else loginPrompt">Don't have an account? <a routerLink = '/sign-up'>Sign up</a></div>
      <ng-template #loginPrompt>Have an account? <a routerLink = '/sign-in'>Sign In</a></ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';
import { SignInComponent } from './sign-in/sign-in.component';
import { SignUpComponent } from './sign-up/sign-up.component';
import { TableComponent } from './pages/table/table.component';
import { EmailsFoundComponent } from './emails-found/emails-found.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmptyComponent } from './empty/empty.component';

export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'sign-in',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }, 
  {
    path:'sign-in',
    component: EmptyComponent
  },

  {
    path:'sign-up',
    component: EmptyComponent
  },

  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    children: [
        {
      path: '',
      loadChildren: './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.module#AdminLayoutModule'
  }]},
]
```

lazy-loaded module routing

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent } from '../../pages/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { UserComponent } from '../../pages/user/user.component';
import { TableComponent } from '../../pages/table/table.component';
import { TypographyComponent } from '../../pages/typography/typography.component';
import { IconsComponent } from '../../pages/icons/icons.component';
import { MapsComponent } from '../../pages/maps/maps.component';
import { NotificationsComponent } from '../../pages/notifications/notifications.component';
import { UpgradeComponent } from '../../pages/upgrade/upgrade.component';

export const AdminLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'dashboard',      component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: 'user',           component: UserComponent },
    { path: 'maillists',          component: TableComponent },
    { path: 'typography',     component: TypographyComponent },
    { path: 'icons',          component: IconsComponent },
    { path: 'emails-found',           component: MapsComponent },
    { path: 'find-emails',  component: NotificationsComponent },
    { path: 'upgrade',        component: UpgradeComponent }
];
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="card card-stats">
      <div class="card-body ">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-5 col-md-4">
            <div class="icon-big text-center icon-warning">
              <img src = "assets/img/hashtag.png">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-7 col-md-8">
            <div class="numbers">
              <p class="card-category">Number of Mail Lists</p>
              <p class="card-title">10
                <p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer ">
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="card card-stats">
      <div class="card-body ">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-5 col-md-4">
            <div class="icon-big text-center icon-warning">
              <img src = "assets/img/at.png">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-7 col-md-8">
            <div class="numbers">
              <p class="card-category">Total Number of Emails</p>
              <p class="card-title">1,345
                <p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer ">
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="card card-stats">
      <div class="card-body ">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-5 col-md-4">
            <div class="icon-big text-center icon-warning">
              <i class="nc-icon nc-vector text-danger"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-7 col-md-8">
            <div class="numbers">
              <p class="card-category">Errors</p>
              <p class="card-title">23
                <p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer ">
        <hr>
        <div class="stats">
          <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> In the last hour
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> -->
  <div>
    <div class="card card-stats">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card ">
      <div class="card-header ">
        <h5 class="card-title">Users Behavior</h5>
        <p class="card-category">24 Hours performance</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body ">
        <canvas id=chartHours width="400" height="100"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer ">
        <hr>
        <div class="stats">
          <i class="fa fa-history"></i> Updated 3 minutes ago
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> -->
<div class="row">
  <div style = "display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:5%" class="col-md-5">
    <div class="card ">
      <div class="card-header ">
        <h5 class="card-title"><i class="nc-icon nc-bullet-list-67"></i> Manage your mailing lists</h5>
        <p class="card-category">Create, delete, add emails etc</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body ">
          <ul>
              <li>Insurance Companies</li>
              <li>Medical Companies</li>
              <li>Fin Tech</li>
              <li>Web Dev</li>
              <li>Accounting</li>
              <li>Law Firms</li>
            </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer ">
        <p>Recently created lists.</p>
        <!-- <div class="legend">
          <i class="fa fa-circle text-primary"></i> Opened
          <i class="fa fa-circle text-warning"></i> Read
          <i class="fa fa-circle text-danger"></i> Deleted
          <i class="fa fa-circle text-gray"></i> Unopened
        </div> -->
        <hr>
        <!-- <div class="stats">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Number of emails sent
        </div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div style = "display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:5%;" class="col-md-5">
      <div class="card ">
        <div class="card-header ">
          <h5 class="card-title"><i class="nc-icon nc-zoom-split text-success"></i> Find Emails</h5>
          <p class="card-category">Reach your target audience using search!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body ">
          <ul>
            <li>info@info.com</li>
            <li>info@info.com</li>
            <li>info@info.com</li>
            <li>info@info.com</li>
            <li>info@info.com</li>
            <li>info@info.com</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer ">
          <p>Recently generated emails</p>
          <hr>
          <!-- <div class="stats">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Number of emails sent
          </div> -->
        </div>
      </div>

  <typography-cmp></typography-cmp>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Please update your questions with source code showing how you display the dashboard component.

Comment: i guess the problem is somewhere else and not related to lazyloading. my first thing to debug would be, adding a console.log or a debugger to the lazyloaded-module's constructor and ngOnInit and check what is different.

Comment: @mr.alex, I added an alert to the constructor of the dashboard component, the alert is still executing even when the dashboard components html does not load. However when I refresh, alert executes and html loads

Comment: Please add the code of your routing module and lazy-loading module

Comment: Do you have an *ngIf in your dashboard.component.html?

Comment: @IvanFrolov, added.

Comment: @mr.alex, not in dashboard but app component html, as shown

Comment: The problem may be because you don't have router-outlet in your app.component.

Comment: @IvanFrolov, added now but issue is still there

Comment: Ok. Can you confirm, that when you clicking on the button the module chunk is actually loading? It should be displayed on network tab filtered by js files only

Comment: might be helpful to add the dashboard.component.html

Comment: @JasonWhite , added.

Comment: @IvanFrolov, checked the network tab. When i click the button, it shows the lazy-loaded module in the network

Comment: alright, there are some things that look a bit confusing to me.

1. why is there a <router-outlet> in every component? from your routes i would say you only need one in AppComponent and AdminLayoutComponent.
2. aren't the path's in your routes conflicting? the empty path should redirectTo SignIn but is alos the entrypoint for AdminLayout. i would check what is happening when you give the AdminLayout a path, like admin` and then try requesting '/admin/dashboard'

Comment: 3. the route-definition for AdminLayout is also looking a bit weird to me. the 'path' and 'loadChildren' property should be everything that is needed (you shouldn't need to add the 'children'-property, because the AdminLayoutRoutes is defining its "children" anyways)

Comment: In fact a <router-outlet> in AdminLayoutComponent is also only needed if there is some shared template-part across all admin-routes

Comment: Took out the <router-outlet> from my signin component and that has seemed to do the trick! New to angular, thanks for the help

Comment: Thank you for these comments! I spent hours looking for a similar problem where "the url changes, but the navigation just works if I refresh the page". It cames out that I had a *ngIf at my router-outlet  *ngIf="(enViewMode$ | async) === ENVIEWMODE.fullscreen" and the condition was just satisfied at ngOnInit.